# UIBarButtonItem custom view aspect fill swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing an app that displays, in the main ViewController, the user's profile image inside a round `UIBarButtonItem`, so I'm using a custom Button with `cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds` enabled, I am resizing the `UIImage`'s width to 75% of `NavigationBar`'s height to fit well in it, I also used `button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`

When I use a squared image(width = height) it works perfect, but if I use a portrait or landscape image it looks like if BarButton was using `.scaleAspectFit`

I already tried to create first a squared `UIImage` cropping original profile image without any luck.

This is my Bar button code:

```
func setProfileButton() {
    let width = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height * 0.75

    if let image = ResizeImage(CFUser.current!.getProfileImage(), to: width) {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goProfile), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: width)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.width / 2
        button.clipsToBounds = true

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
}
```

This is ResizeImage code:

```
func ResizeImage(_ image: UIImage, to width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let size = image.size
    let ratio = width / image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height * ratio
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio,height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Here is the app working with squared image

[image: Here is the app working with squared image]

And this is with a portrait image

[image: And this is with a portrait image]

Thanks for your help! :)

PD: I'm using Xcode 10 and Swift 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the portrait image has different dimensions unlike square image, calculate the minimum dimension and modify the image size accordingly.

Replace method `ResizeImage(_ image: UIImage, to width: CGFloat) -> UIImage?` with below.

```
func ResizeImage(_ image: UIImage, to width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let ratio = width / image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height * ratio
    let dimension = min(width, height)
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: dimension, height: dimension)

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: targetSize.width, height: targetSize.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Square image:

[image]

Portrait image:

[image]

Comment: I did it but now I get half of the image I had before